# Integration own widget angularjs

Tags: angularjs, widget, integration

> *Check dashboardCtrl.js and integrate the following widgets with the final JSON data format (start with getDashboard() function:
>
> - first
> - secound
> - third*

**I should write it like this?**

$http.get(Dashboard)function(){}? or function getDashboard(){}
and if someone know how to integrate, please, send me link, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information for us to help you. But if you were asked to integrate / merge some content **into** JSON, then use **$http.post()**. An example:

```
// Some data to send 
var my_data = {"widgets":[{"widget1":""},{"widget2":""},{"widget3":""}],"JSONfile":"file.json"};

$http.post(url,my_data).then(function(result){
  /* Success */
}, function(error){ 
  /* Error */ 
});
```

To open and modify JSON you can use PHP:

```
<?php
/* Get the data from POST request
  $dataReceived = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $myFile = json_decode( $dataReceived );
  $myWidget = $myFile->widgets;
  $JSON_file_name = $myFile->JSONfile;
*/
$content = json_decode( file_get_contents($JSON_file_name), true );
$content['content'][] = ['widget'=>$myWidget];
$newJsonString = json_encode($content, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
file_put_contents($JSON_file_name, $newJsonString);
?>
```

To retrieve data from JSON:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(result){
  $scope.my_data = result.data;
}, function(error){ 
  /* Error */ 
  $scope.my_data = null;
});
```